# Input Elements with Flexbox Adds Extra Spacing in Webkit

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a simple form with an email field and a submit button that I am applying a flexbox layout to. The flexbox itself works fine, but it appears that webkit adds a bit of extra spacing next to input elements (non input elements appear to be fine). This problem doesn't occur in IE11 and Firefox but is present in Opera and Chrome. Because IE and Firefox don't do this, it is difficult to create a consistent cross-browser UI. Is there a some property that I can override to prevent this extra space from being added? Or is this a bug?

```
<section id="inputContent">
    <input type="Email"/>
    <input type="Submit"/>
</section>

section
{
    display:flex;
}
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Dragonseer/2H2P5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the border and the margin that makes it look so, add

```
input{
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid;

}
```

and there will be no space

http://jsfiddle.net/2H2P5/2/

Comment: That did it. For those who are styling their buttons and don't want a border, set the border color to match the button color.

Comment: I have the same issue, but your answer didn't fix it.

Comment: @Wazery if it didn't work its not the same issue as the OP confirmed it worked. You should ask a new  question rather than making a useless comment.